# The selected team doesn't have an iOS Developer Program membership

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm attempting to add myself as a developer on a team for iOS.  (It's a university program)

I go into Xcode, select the team name, and click "fix issue" (earlier it was having code signing problems, which I fixed).  It returns this error:  "The selected team doesn't have an iOS Developer Program membership"

This is false, I know for sure that the team is an iOS development team.  And on developer.apple.com it shows me as logged in on the iOS team. Xcode just won't recognize this fact.  Please help.

(Video of problem: http://screencast.com/t/mu5mV8WmD)

Comment: why dont you manually do it?

Comment: @Ramshad What do you mean?

Comment: explain this one "I'm attempting to add myself as a developer on a team for iOS"..

Comment: Perhaps this will clarify:  http://screencast.com/t/mu5mV8WmD

Comment: try with Team->Add an Account. then let me know the result.

Comment: Fix issue has rarely worked for me. As Ramshad suggested try doing it via Apple Dev site.

Comment: How does one go about that?

Answer (score 18):

I got this error when the developer account from Xcode was using an old Apple id email address. Deleting that account from Xcode and adding it back again solved the issue for me.

Comment: If you're new to Xcode, this can be done in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem after i changed password to my apple id account, it is seem to be that somehow it unable to request your data about your account and certificate. So it's "Select a team with an iOS Developer Program membership and try again.".

Confirm that deleting account from Xcode and adding it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your password, go to Xcode - preferences and change the password in the relevant account

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was removing it and adding it again as suggested above (not sure if its necessary) and then selecting another team, and then selecting the original one again. If you are only the member of one team you may just have to remove and add again.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I have solved the same problem. I had a valid membership account. But it wasnt recognizing it. 
So;

- I have made the Team to none in (General/Identity)
- Then clean The project
- Changed the Provisioning profile to Automatic in (BuildSettings/CodeSigning)
- the most important part (I had add the device using its id in (membercenter/Devices)
- I have added a new account using (General/Identity)  ( try this if selecting the previous account from here doesnt work)
- Then I have started the app, and it works in the real device

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this fixed.  I just talked to my account admin, and he added me as a new project under the university account, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when iTunes Connect went down. I had a feeling it was down because I traced the error back to bad account credentials, and twitter confirmed my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlZ6b.png)

I didn't had the access to the development team. After getting access to the development team I was still facing the same error. Selecting the right team solved the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33951374)